# install Rstudio on Ubuntu 20.4 Error (code=exited, status=127)

Tags: r, installation, rstudio-server

I want to install Rstudio after I have installed R on my ubuntu 20.4

Everything is fine till I want to execute the actual installation with
`sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.3.1073-amd64.deb`

```
rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-17 11:35:12 CEST; 11ms ago
    Process: 128920 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=127)
```

Why do I get the `(code=exited, status=127)` and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by getting to the one for Ubuntu18/Bionic Beaver instead:

```
https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb
```