# Why do I get a startup error of R, when I try to start Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, startup-error

New information:

I have installed a previous version of r-studio (rstudio-1.3.1093-amd64.deb) as was implied in the link that @MViking sent me, and know I am getting a more informative error.

Firstly, at the terminal I get the following message:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notifyRCrashed' of undefined"
```

Then, the popup window of rstudio appears as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer will help with your error message "The R session process exited with code 127"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448572/install-rstudio-on-ubuntu-20-4-error-code-exited-status-127

Comment: What happens when you start `R` in a normal terminal window?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel When I start R in the terminal I get the normal R workspace interface

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing the default R and rstudio version!